# Half pie chart with multiple values

Tags: d3.js

How to create Half pie arc in d3
I'm following an example with full pie chart. How do I create Half pie chart?

code so far

http://tributary.io/inlet/5260888

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Solution: http://tributary.io/inlet/5273835

[d3's pie layout](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Pie-Layout) has functions to set the [startAngle](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Pie-Layout#wiki-startAngle) and [engAngle](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Pie-Layout#wiki-endAngle) properties which can create partial pie charts.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar requirement, however the missing part isn't half, but a changing fraction of the whole. in order to achieve this, I just set the "stroke" and "fill" for the missing segment to "none".